# Italian election definitive results?

Tags: election, italy

http://elezioni.interno.gov.it/camera/scrutini/20180304/scrutiniCI

This page shows the results for the Italian elections; however, they appear not to be complete (Sezioni: 61.374 / 61.401).

My questions are: why are they not complete yet? when can we hope to have the final definitive results? If they actually are definitive and complete, where can I find them?

I don't speak Italian so my research ability is limited.

Comment: If you open the "circoscrizione" drop down menu and you start selecting the options one by one, you'll see that there are 25 missing from "Lazio 1" and 2 missing from "Lazio 2", all others are fully completed. I don't have an answer, but this should help in restricting the search area.

Comment: I am not an expert, but 1) the last results were sent on the 6th of march 2) there is a note that says that some results were directly sent to the _Appellate court_. That's probably because somebody (e.g., a citizen, an observer from a party, etc.) has denounced irregularities. So, the elections might not be definitive until the courts have looked on the issue. Having said that I have not heard any major issues, so the results will probably not change in any significant measure.

Comment: I do not know if you still need them, but today they are complete.

(0) Go to https://elezionistorico.interno.gov.it/
(1) Select the type of election. In your case Camera or Senato.
(2) Select the date. In your case 04/03/2018.
(3) Select the Area (Italy, Valle d'Aosta, Estero)
(4) Select the Circoscrizione/Regione (Electoral district)